# Distribute $27$ balls evenly among three boxes, transferring exactly $n$ balls in the $n$-th move

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> There are $3$ boxes, namely, $A$, $B$, and $C$. There are $27$ balls in box $C$. You have to make equal the number of balls in each box. At every $n$-th move, you must transfer exactly $n$ balls from one box to another. You cannot transfer balls between box $A$ and $B$.
>
> How many moves are required to equal the number of balls in all the boxes (if possible)?
>
> A) $7\quad$ B) $8\quad$ C) $9\quad$ D) Not possible

My try:

Since we must start from $1$ and bigger numbers like $7$,$8$, $\ldots$ might not be so appropriate to fulfill our question. I tried to make a list of those numbers whose sum or difference are equal to $9$ (as we want $9$ in every box). Here what I have:

$$\begin{align}
1+2+3+4+5-6 &=9 \\
2+7 &=9 \\
2+3+4 &=9 \\
\cdots
\end{align}$$
But I could not put them together to get an appropriate solution.  Can anyone help?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Right now, it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want $9$ balls in each box which will require at least 18 balls being moved. This is at least $6$ moves as $\sum_{i=1}^6i = 21$. But it will require an even number of balls being moved after the first 18 as we can't move balls between A and B so after the 18 we are essentially just moving balls back and forth to and from C to fit the move requirements. So the minimum is now $7$ moves with $\sum_{i=1}^7i = 28$ balls being moved.

We can do it in $7$ moves by moving $3$ balls to A on moves one and two, $7$ balls to B on moves three and four, $5$ balls from B to C on move five, $6$ balls to A on move six, and $7$ balls to B on move seven. This results in each box having $9$ balls.

Comment: I think there can be more such solutions like                         
 A : 1+3+4-5+6          , B : 2+7.                                                   In both cases 7 is the correct answer.